# Reading an ESRI XML Workspace Document with python or other FOSS

Tags: python, gdal, xml, geodatabase-xml

I've recently run into data in "ESRI XML Workspace Format," I have never run into this format before, and can't find any reference to using it with FOSS tools, or any documentation on the format the geometry is stored in.

My goal is to read this data with python so i can processes it with Shapely, but i'm open to any FOSS solution for reading it.

Possibilities:

- GDAL/ORG
- QGIS
- A python library

I am not interested in any solution using ArcPY.

Here is a sample of one of the records from the file.

```
<Record xsi:type='esri:Record'>
    <Values xsi:type='esri:ArrayOfValue'>
        <Value xsi:type='xs:int'>830</Value>
        <Value xsi:type='xs:string'>Bankhead Jones</Value>
        <Value xsi:type='xs:string'>Bureau of Land Management</Value>
        <Value xsi:type='xs:int'>2</Value><Value xsi:type='xs:short'>2</Value>
        <Value xsi:type='esri:PolygonB'>
            <Bytes>MwAAIPjj2b8URlrAYG9mt8AORkAMJpONhkNawCCTb/2OEUZAAQAAAB0AAAAAAAAADCaTjYZDWsBI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</Bytes>
        </Value>
        <Value xsi:type='xs:string'>{9E4D50CD-773F-426A-9D85-ACEB53A6651E}</Value>
        <Value xsi:type='xs:string'>BFAHRER</Value>
        <Value xsi:type='xs:dateTime'>2015-06-23T20:07:05</Value>
        <Value xsi:type='xs:string'>BFAHRER</Value>
        <Value xsi:type='xs:dateTime'>2015-06-23T20:07:05</Value>
        <Value xsi:type='xs:double'>0.00059271317454369463</Value>
        <Value xsi:type='xs:double'>0.12326579683440851</Value>
    </Values>
</Record>
```

The data I am trying to read is from http://www.blm.gov/wy/st/en/resources/public_room/gis/datagis/state/state-own.html

Comment: This is to be imported into a file geodatabase, which I don't know is a capability of any FOSS tool, including the ESRI File Geodatabase libraries for GDAL/QGIS... if you're stuck I can create a file geodatabase and convert to shapefile or other and send it via dropbox... unless you have to do this a lot, then you should get an 'arcgis for home' version...

Comment: @DPSSpatial That would be great if you could convert that to a file geodatabase for me. I dont currently have a windows machine, so setting up arcgis requires a bunch of additional steps.

This data is going into a project im working on to create a nationwide dataset of public lands(more on that at https://github.com/OpenBounds/PublicLands ) and out of ~250 sources from various government sources this is the first i've run into that i cant totally handle with FOSS tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the geometry encoding, see

- [Spec for ArcGIS XML Schema of GeoDatabase](http://downloads.esri.com/support/whitepapers/ao_/XML_Schema_of_Geodatabase.pdf), Appendix A.
- [Geometry types in xml geodatabase](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.0/ArcGISDevHelp/TechnicalDocuments/Geodatabase/XML_Schema/XMLSchema.htm#Geometry_types)

I don't see any reference to the `esri:polygonb` tag, but to my eyes this looks like very like [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). (One or two Equals signs at the end would confirm this, but [aren't guaranteed to be there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6916831) - like in your example)

If it is base64, it would be possible to parse the XML in Python and write it to a postgres database, but not sure how much effort would be involved.

Comment: The [Geodatabase XML Schema](http://support.esri.com/white-paper/695) white paper states the binary format is indeed Base64.